# GraphQL.EntityFramework: override e.g. contains filter to do EF.Functions.Collate(..., "BINARY_AI")

Tags: graphql, accent-insensitive

Recently I did a POC with hotchocolate and I was able to override the query behaviour on the contains/like filter on strings so that I could do a case-insensitive and accent-insensitive search. I am looking for extension points in GraphQL.EntityFramework to provide me with the same behaviour.
Is it possible to do something like thisn in GraphQL.EntityFramework.

I was hoping to find documentation how to implement something like this.